# Can we convert the apps made in Ionic to iOS

Tags: ionic-framework, ios11, react-native-ios, ionic-native, ionic-view

I am a newbie in ios developement. Please help can we convert ionic sdk app to iOS apps.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with convert? You can build an iOS app with ionic.

Comment: Thomas I built an app in ionic but want to convert the same so that same can be used with swift

Comment: Or The coding that is used in ionic can be same used in Xcode to run the same app that is made in ionic.

Comment: Ionic runs the java-script in a native swift web-view, so you cant convert the typescript to swift

Comment: If you want to have your app entirely in swift then yeah you'll have to re write it. your original question suggest you want to make an ios app which you can do in ionic with typescript...

Comment: @IraW yes This is the same